# Java Bound Mistmatch

Tags: java, generics

I am writing classes that represents mathematical items. They came in pairs: one (referred as `C`) defines an element of a set, the other (`B`) represents the set. The relevant classes are:

```
public abstract class Vector<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>>          implements Element<C,B, Vector<C,B>, VectorialSpace<C,B>> { }
public abstract class VectorialSpace<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>>  implements Ring<C,B, Vector<C,B>, VectorialSpace<C,B>> { }


public abstract class PolyCoeff<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>> extends Vector<C,B>  { }
public class RingPoly<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>>           extends VectorialSpace<C,B> { }


public interface Constant<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>> { }
public interface BaseRing<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>> { }

public interface Element<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>, E extends Element<C,B,E,R>, R extends Ring<C,B,E,R>> extends Constant<E,R> { }
public interface Ring<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>, E extends Element<C,B,E,R>, R extends Ring<C,B,E,R>>    extends BaseRing<E,R> { }
```

Note that:

- In every class the generic type `C` implements the interface `Constant<C,B>` and the generic type `B` implements the interface `BaseRing<C,B>`.
- `PolyCoeff<C,B>` is not the only subclass of `Vector<C,B>` in my workspace, nor is `RingPoly<C,B>` the only subclass of `VectorialSpace<C,B>`.

The classes and interfaces previous described don't have any problem. The following however does:

```
public class Homomorphism< C1 extends Constant<C1,B1>, B1 extends BaseRing<C1,B1>,      
        C2 extends Constant<C2,B2>, B2 extends BaseRing<C2,B2> > { 

    public static <C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>> 
        Homomorphism<C,B,PolyCoeff<C,B>,RingPoly<C,B>> ringToPolyRingHomeo(B ring){
        [...]
    } 
}
```

The errors reported are:

`Bound mismatch: The type PolyCoeff<C,B> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <C2 extends Constant<C2,B2>> of the type Homomorphism<C1,B1,C2,B2>`

`Bound mismatch: The type RingPoly<C,B> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <B2 extends BaseRing<C2,B2>> of the type Homomorphism<C1,B1,C2,B2>`

`PolyCoeff<C,B>` extends the abstract class `Vector<C,B>`, which in turn implements the interface `Element<C,B,Vector<C,B>,VectorialSpace<C,B>`, which in turn extends the interface `Constant<Vector<C,B>, VectorialSpace<C,B>>`. Thus, `PolyCoeff<C,B>` implements `Constant<Vector<C,B>, VectorialSpace<C,B>>` **and** is a specific type of `Vector<C,B>`.

My question is: why that is not sufficient and how can I solve the problem considering that I have *other* subclasses of `Vector<C,B>`?

Comment: Just a warning that with bounds like that, you're heading for a world of hurt when you actually get to using your classes. It is likely that you have cohesion and coupling design problems. Try to separate out the various concerns into separate classes and compose your more complex classes by *using* rather than *extending* the simpler ones - composition in preference to inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to satisfy the type bounds of `C2 extends Constant<C2, B2>`, `PolyCoeff<C, B>` must implement `Constant<PolyCoeff<C, B>, RingPoly<C, B>>`, which it does not.

I realize that this does not tell you what you need to change in order to make your code work.  I suspect this will require some of your type bounds to say `? super ...` or `? extends ...`, but I have not analyzed your classes enough to tell where those should go.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way: now `Vector` and `VectorialSpace` have the following heading:

`public interface Vector<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>, V extends Vector<C,B,V,VS>, VS extends VectorialSpace<C,B,V,S>> extends Element<C,B,V,VS>`

`public interface VectorialSpace<C extends Constant<C,B>, B extends BaseRing<C,B>, V extends Vector<C,B,V,VS>, VS extends VectorialSpace<C,B,V,S>> extends Ring<C,B,V,VS>`